# Problem Changing input field attribute depending on checkbox status

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a checkbox to display some input fields wrapped in a div. When the checkbox is clicked the divs are displaying correctly, when not clicked the divs hide which is working fine. By default the input fields in the div are not required (optional).

I want to create a Js logic whereby if the user clicks the checkbox the fields should change the attribute to be mandatory/required.

Am a Js learner,, please assist?

**Checkbox code to hide or diaplay the div below**

```
<label class="spouse-me">
    <h1 class="pumba">Spouse</h1>
    <input type="hidden" class="spouse" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="spouse" value="1" class="spouse" onclick="checkMark()">
</label>
```

**Div being displayed or hidden by the checkbox**

```
//Parent div
<div class="spouseDetail" id="spouseDetail" style="display:none;">
  //Child div
  <div class="form-line registar love {{ $errors->has('spousename') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" style="margin-left: 0px;">
    <input type="text-area" class="form-input" name="spousename" id="spouseName" value="{{ old('spousename') }}">
    <label>Spouse Name *</label>
    <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
    <div class="check-label"></div>
    @if ($errors->has('spousename'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('spousename') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>

<div class="form-line registar love {{ $errors->has('spousedob') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  <input type="date" class="form-input" name="spousedob" id="spouseDob" value="{{ old('spousedob') }}">
  <label>Date of Birth *</label>
  <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
  <div class="check-label"></div>
  @if ($errors->has('spousedob'))
        <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('spousedob') }}</strong>
        </span>
  @endif
</div>

</div>
```

**Javascript Function**

```
  function checkMark() {
      var checkBox = document.getElementById("spouse");
      var text = document.getElementById("spouseDetail");

      // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
      if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        text.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like this.

```
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
    var inputElm = document.getElementsByTagName(INPUT);
    for(var i=0; i<inputElm.length; i++) {
        inputElm[i].required = true;
    }
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
```

Comment: why do you use a for loop?

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns a collection of input elements. You may iterate it to mark all input fields as "required".